# using databinding in codebehind

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a page where I bind a command to a button. When I click it I calls a method where I get the data I want from an API.What if I don't want to only bind the data at the view but also use these data in code behind?! 
Lets say this is my view :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.Pages.JohnDoePage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.ViewModel;assembly=HelloWorld">
   <StackLayout Padding="20, 10" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Button Command="{Binding JohnDoe}"
                Text="Data about John Doe" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

the code behihnd :

```
    Models.Info info;
    public JohnDoePage(Models.Info info)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new InfoDetailsViewModel(info);
        this.info= info;

     // i want to use the data here 
     //using the data
     }
```

the view model :

```
     Data _data;
    public Data Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _data) return;
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand JohnDoe
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                var Dataa = await _apiServices.InfoAboutJohnDOe();
            });
        }
    }
```

and the service where I get the data I need is OK. I'm using the same  viewmodel for binding different commands, and I don't know if this is possible by the way so I'm stuck. Any idea how can I use the data I get in the view code-behind?? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just maintain a class level reference to your VM?

```
Models.Info info;
InfoDetailsViewModel vm;

public JohnDoePage(Models.Info info)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new InfoDetailsViewModel(info);
    BindingContext = vm;
    this.info= info;
 }
```

Comment: yeah, ok..but what about the data? Because `vm = new InfoDetailsViewModel(info);` the `info` are another data which I get from another command.

Comment: Just expose a Data property in your VM, then you can access it from the code-behind

Comment: of course. I already did that but I didn't get the right reference of the model in code-behind. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Save the result of your Service call as a public property

```
public <TargetType> Dataa { get; set; }
```

and save the DataContext of your JohnDoePage as a member.

```
JohnDoePageViewModel dataContext = (JohnDoePageViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

Because then you are able to get the information from the ViewModel.

```
var data = dataContext.Dataa;
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hey Mark, a little to late, but I tried your solution and my app breaks. I think it happens because `var data = dataContext.Dataa;` this checks for the data  before the button is tapped. Any idea on how to handle this?! :) @mark